# "there's one place to go - this is it" or similar, Sinatra?

Tags: identify-this-song, swing

I've spent more than an hour to find a song with a lyric containing something like "If there's one place to go - this is it" (or "I know one place"...), probably by Frank Sinatra or someone making similar music.

It must be very well known since it was used in many movies/tv shows. I'm not sure but I think the song was about Las Vegas (or maybe New York?).

I really hope this incomplete information leads to someone recognising it, neither lyrics search engines nor find-by-humming engines brought up something useful.

As far as I remember the melody should be close to this: https://onlinesequencer.net/758409

Comment: Do you have any other clues? I'd really wish to help

Comment: @IdiotStyle I tried to create the melody using an online sequencer, maybe this could help. Very poorly but recognizable I guess. (Linked in question)

Comment: I can't seem to recognize it sorry :I it may be the opening to a song that you sometimes don't hear in all versions (so mostly a broadway piece)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're talking Sinatra and New York the obvious song is ***New York New York***

***Chicago*** and ***My Kind of Town*** are about Chicago

Comment: Unfortunately, all three of these songs were obvious enough so that I could already rule them out.